# iCloud won't accept my password

Tags: icloud, password, iphone

iCloud won't accept my password even after going to iTunes and restoring data from iPhone. I cannot use my phone to call or receive calls. I have the iPhone 4S.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you updated to the latest iOS?

Comment: You could reset the password